# question about location of variable in memory

Tags: c++

we know meaning of pointers  for example to get location of variable

```
int t=9;
```

we use following notation

```
int *p=&t;
```

how can i obtain  address of variable in memory by bitwise operatos and bits manipulation?    can i do it in general or what is equivalent of pointer in bit world?i am using c++

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a specific problem you'd like to solve that way?

Comment: If you're asking how to get a pointer to a particular bit in `t` (say, the 12th bit), then you can't. There are no pointers-to-bits in C++: the smallest addressable unit of memory is the `char`. It would be legal for an implementation to provide, as an extension, a means of addressing smaller units, but personally I've never encountered anything like that. I suppose that arguably the iterators obtained from `std::vector<bool>` are in some respects like a pointer to a bit, so if you're looking to implement something yourself, look there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bit wise operators like `and` and `or`, you can't get the address of an arbitrary variable, no.

At some point, you *have* to use `&`.

If you're talking about manipulating bits *within* one of the more basic types, there are (at least) two approaches you can take:

- Specify bit-field structures such as `struct { int bit:3 }` where the number after the `:` is the number of bits; or
- Use bitmasking tchniques like `threebits = sixteenbits & 0x07;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the adress via bitwise operators. You have to use the "address of" operator.